# How to use Eclipse (remote) debugger with spawn-fcgi (or similar process launchers)

Tags: eclipse, nginx, gdb, fastcgi

I can successfully (cross-) compile and (remote-) debug C applications with Eclipse. But I have a bunch of FCGI-applications that only work when started with spawn-fcgi (because they need to be connected to the already running nginx web server this way), such as:

```
sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -s/tmp/fcgiApp.socket -n /var/www/fcgiApp/fcgiApp.bin
```

Is there any way to instruct the Eclipse GDB to copy the latest binary  to the server, then launch the application in the special way outlined above, and finally attach to the spawned fcgi process?

Note that I have put "cross" and "remote" in parentheses, because I think that the actual problem (debugging a spawned process) persists if I run Eclipse and the Webserver on the same local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer myself, more exactly a workaround for the specific problem with fcgi:

It is possible to create the required socket connection within the application itself, like in this code snippet:

```
#if STANDALONE
    int sockfd = FCGX_OpenSocket("/tmp/fcgiTest.socket", 1024);
    char command[] = "chmod ag+rwx /tmp/fcgiTest.socket";
    system( command );
#endif
    FCGX_Request request;
    FCGX_Init();

#if STANDALONE
    FCGX_InitRequest(&request, sockfd, 0);
#else
    FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0);
#endif
```

So for a standalone application that can be used for debugging (use `#define STANDALONE 1`), the socket is created as a normal user, then for debugging purposes write access is granted to everyone, in particular to *www-data* i.e the web server.

For deployment, you would use `#define STANDALONE 0` and start the process as user *www-data* using `spawn-fcgi` as usual.